# How to get the sum of the prices of all items in the Magazine? - django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Magazine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='u_item')
```

How to get the sum of the prices of all items in the Magazine?

in views:

```
...
    user = request.user
    magazins = Magazine.objects.filter(owner= user)
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You want a sum of prices per magazine? Why not just loop over the items and add the prices? Maybe if you are more specific where the problem is, we can help better.

Comment: Welcome! I can not refer to item_price. In a many to many relation

Comment: `for item in self.items` in a `Magazine` function?

Comment: I need a more detailed explanation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [aggregations in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

It might look something like below:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
owners_magazines = Magazine.objects.filter(owner='Your owner')
total = 0;
for magazine in owners_magazines:
    item_values_with_total = magazine.items.values().annotate(total=Sum('item_price'))
    total += <Read appropriately from item_values_with_total>
```

You can use further try to group things together. The returned value will have a field called `total` which will have the required sum.

Edit -

You can try a non-ORM solution to understand it better

```
from django.db.models import Sum
    owners_magazines = Magazine.objects.filter(owner='Your owner')
    total = 0;
    for magazine in owners_magazines:
        all_items = magazines.items_set.all()
        for item in all_items:
            total += item.item_price

    print total
```

Comment: This code return in manage.py shell this error: name 'items' is not defined

Comment: Try `item` or `Item` instead of `items` since you have specifically stated that.

Comment: I added 'items' Magazine.objects.filter(owner=user).values('items').annotate(total=Sum('item_price')) but return error: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'item_price' into field. Choices are: id, name, owner, items - but this is many to many relation

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Magazine -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {'owner': 1}

Comment: Try deleting one entry from magazine for that owner, so that only a single result is returned. If it works for that, can be made to work for more than one later.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! Now i have: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'ValuesQuerySet'. I try int(item_values_with_total) but error is still displaying

Comment: Can you paste your print valuesqueryset, you need to pick the total value inside that just like from a dictionary.

Comment: This queryset return: <Magazin: user_item>  where user_item is name of Magazin in database

Answer (score 1):

Use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

for m in Magazine.objects.all():
   total = m.items_set.all().annotate(total=Sum('item_price'))
   print 'Total cost for items in {0} is {1}'.format(m,total)
```

Comment: 'total' return [<Item: Item name>], not prices of all item in this magazine. print output: Total cost for items in user_magazin is [<Item: Abc>]